# Strange unhandled exception; Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, sdl

When I try to call SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha, I get this unhandled exception: "Unhandled exception at 0x68125981 (SDL.dll) in herorpg.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000013C."

### Code:

```
SDL_Surface* load_image ( char* filename ) {
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;
    loadedImage = IMG_Load ( filename );

    if ( loadedImage != NULL ) {
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha ( loadedImage );
        SDL_FreeSurface ( loadedImage );
    }

    return optimizedImage;
}

bool init ( SDL_Surface*& screen ) {

    //Initialize SDL
    if ( SDL_Init ( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 ) return false;
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode ( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_FULLSCREEN );
    if ( screen == NULL ) return false;

    //Set the caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption ( "Hero RPG", NULL );

    return true;
}
```

### Main:

```
int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {
init ( screen );

load_image ( "graphics\\background\\overworld" );

return 0;
}
```

### Other:

If I comment out

```
    //if ( loadedImage != NULL ) {
    //  optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha ( loadedImage );
    //  SDL_FreeSurface ( loadedImage );
    //}
```

and change

```
    loadedImage = IMG_Load ( filename );
```

to

```
    optimizedImage = IMG_Load ( filename );
```

the image loads fine. So I know there is no problem with the file name.

### Question:

This is the exact function I used in the last program I designed, and it worked fine last time. I think the answer to this will be outside of the box. Why would I be receiving this unhandled exception?

Comment: It seems to me like this code will never do anything, since `loadedImage` will remain NULL throughout the function. Your if-test should always fail. I suppose you want to be doing `loadedImage = IMG_Load ( filename );` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing some bug testing a second ago and copied the wrong code. It's fixed now.

Comment: What happens if  you just comment out the  line with `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` in it?

Comment: A black screen. `optimizedImage` can't be accessed for some reason.

Comment: The code you've given compiles and runs fine on my Linux machine, with some small additions. The ONLY way I made it crash on `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` was by not calling `SDL_SetVideoMode` beforehand. Or by calling `SDL_Quit` before loading the image. Are you sure `SDL_SetVideoMode` is succeeding?

Comment: Like I stated in the question, if I comment out the `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` and make some small adjustments it runs fine. That leads me to believe `SDL_SetVideoMode` is working fine.

Comment: 0x0000013C is a bad pointer (I mean, it's *always* a bad pointer, too low). Can't you run on a debug version of SDL?

Comment: I have, is there something I could do while debugging that would help to solve my problem?

Comment: At least find out which line triggers the access violation. And have you checked the return value of init()?

Comment: Well yes, I know which line triggers it. `optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha ( loadedImage );` gives me the error. This was already stated in the comments earlier. `optimizedImage` can't be accessed.

Comment: No, you know which line _causes_ it. That's not quite the same thing. Just because it works when you comment out that line, doesn't necessarily mean that that is the line that is actually throwing the exception. What do you see when you break into the process with your debugger at the point at which the exception is caught? Sorry if you've already said this, I just want to be sure.

Comment: And to repeat @QuasarDonkey, just because it _seems_ to work when you comment something out, doesn't necessarily mean that `SDL_SetVideoMode` is succeeding. Don't assume, check its return value.

Comment: Everything is returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha) it has this line:

> Of course, the video surface must be initialised using SDL_SetVideoMode before this function is called, or it will segfault.

Seeing I don't see a call to `SDL_SetVideoMode` in your posted code, I can assume this is probably the cause.

Comment: Like that? If you need more let me know

Comment: It might be about color quality setting (32bit, 16bit ?)

Comment: The function I'm calling, `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` changes the color quality setting.